# How to let the user create cron jobs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have an Ruby on Rails application which allows the user the execute certain jobs. These jobs are handled and executed by Sidekiq.

Now I want to give the user the possibility to schedule these jobs and like cron jobs allow them to be recurring on certain dates and time. The question is how to do this?

All Gems I have come across so far, like whenever, rufus, sidetiq or simple cron jobs only allow for the job to be hardcoded in a file. But what I want is a job that is set by the user and stored in the database.

The obvious way would be to create a cron that checks the database every minute for jobs that are due, executes them and sets the date and time to the next scheduled point. But this way also involved a lot of coding and seems to be a little complicated. Also I see it as a fake cron, because there is simply one cron job that always checks the database.

What I would really like is a solution where the user actually creates a cron job, but I didn't come across anything so far that does this. Also it doesn't have to be a Gem. A more simpler way of just doing this would be enough. And I'd like to think that I can't be the only one who wants to do something like this.

Comment: I don't think you should ever let your user create actual cron jobs on your server.  You (ie your app) needs to stay in total control of what scheduled jobs are available, and all the user can do is to choose which ones to run, and when.  I would have a cron job which calls a rake task, which runs all the pending jobs.  I wouldn't call this a "fake cron".

Comment: Seriously don't do this. The amount of control you're handing over is immense. What's to stop them doing a cron job of `rm -rf /var/www` or cat'ing config/database.yml and dumping the users table into an email to themselves.

Comment: If you want to schedule a task every X period of time, and your user only sets when and the task (as you said), you could try doing it with delayedjob ` class.delay(run_at: 5.hours.from_now).method(param)` and call recursive in the method. Of course you will have some delay of excecution (even if the first thing in your method is calling the recursion). It should be some similar way to do it with Sidekiq (really don't know). Be careful with overlapping of tasks.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answers, but the user is of course not in total control over the system. I will allow him to do cron jobs, but will only give him a limited number of commands that can be executed, so there is that.

Comment: DelayedJob is nice and I've used it before, but calling it over and over again seems like the same thing as running a cron that checks for available jobs all the time. Basically what I want is one of the gems I listed (whenever, rufus etc.) to not get its data from a file, but rather from a database. Can't believe that there is no solution for that.

Comment: @Thomas I want to implement something similar to what you are trying to do.
Is there any solution? How did you implement this?